# How to get create a vector from a curve?

Tags: revit-api, revit, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the concept of 'curve' in Revit API, but I'm basically trying to create a vector from a curve. What I was guessing was creating a vector from both end points of the curve(using GetEndPoint class), but it seems like it's not a thing in Revit API.

I need you guys' help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XYZ pstart = Curve.GetEndPoint(0) # start XYZ point
XYZ pend = Curve.GetEndPoint(1) # end XYZ point
XYZ v = (pend - pstart).Normalize() # normalised vector pointing along curve
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a thing, and it sounds like youre using the correct classes. If I have a `Curve` (which is also a `Line`, and a vector), I can investigate it like this:

```
Curve.GetEndPoint(0) # start XYZ point
Curve.GetEndPoint(1) # end XYZ point
Curve.Evaluate(0.5, True) # middle XYZ point
```

If I want to create a new `Line`, I could do it like this:

```
newLine = Line.CreateBound(XYZ(0,0,0), XYZ(5,2,0))
```

You can then draw the `Line` as a detail line (both points of `newLine` share the same `Z` value, so you need to be in a plan view):

```
doc.Create.NewDetailCurve(ui.ActiveView, newLine )
```

In my experience, a `Curve` and `Line` is pretty interchangable - What are you wanting to do?